# I can not compile and run spring pet clinic with maven

Tags: spring-boot, maven

I am using Windows and when I want to run sf pet clinic with maven, it gives the following message:

```
C:\Users\mramz\spring-framework-petclinic>./mvnw.cmd jetty:run-war
'.' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

When I remove ./ from it's first, it gives the following error when downloading:

```
C:\Users\mramz\spring-framework-petclinic>mvnw.cmd jetty:run-war
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
Downloading from repository.spring.milestone: https://repo.spring.io/milestone/org/springframework/data/spring-data-bom/2021.1.0-RC1/spring-data-bom-2021.1.0-RC1.pom
[ERROR] [ERROR] Some problems were encountered while processing the POMs:
[ERROR] Non-resolvable import POM: Could not transfer artifact org.springframework.data:spring-data-bom:pom:2021.1.0-RC1 from/to repository.spring.milestone (https://repo.spring.io/milestone): Connect to repo.spring.io:443 [repo.spring.io/35.243.130.159] failed: Connection timed out: connect @ line 94, column 25
[ERROR] 'dependencies.dependency.version' for org.springframework.data:spring-data-jpa:jar is missing. @ line 139, column 21
 @
[ERROR] The build could not read 1 project -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR]   The project org.springframework.samples:spring-framework-petclinic:5.3.20 (C:\Users\mramz\spring-framework-petclinic\pom.xml) has 2 errors
[ERROR]     Non-resolvable import POM: Could not transfer artifact org.springframework.data:spring-data-bom:pom:2021.1.0-RC1 from/to repository.spring.milestone (https://repo.spring.io/milestone): Connect to repo.spring.io:443 [repo.spring.io/35.243.130.159] failed: Connection timed out: connect @ line 94, column 25 -> [Help 2]
[ERROR]     'dependencies.dependency.version' for org.springframework.data:spring-data-jpa:jar is missing. @ line 139, column 21
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/ProjectBuildingException
[ERROR] [Help 2] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/UnresolvableModelException
```

I also used ip changer software but it did not work

sf pet clinic link : https://github.com/spring-petclinic/spring-framework-petclinic

What should I do exactly?

Comment: It is not allowed to access spring.io milestone repos...this example has many issue from a Maven point of view (using eclipse plugin which is dead for a long time.. )... `'.' is not recognized as an internal or external command,` this is caused while using linux convention instead of windows `.\mvnw.cmd jetty:run-war`...

Comment: @khmarbaise Thanks but what should I do?Where can I get this repo?I saw in a tutorial that the teacher downloaded this.